# Check wether a JSON is sorted in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, sorting

Hello I have a json file and I am attempting to ***check*** if the data being read is sorted. So i can return true or false based if it is or not. Unfortunately I don't know how to go about this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
public void Trial () throws JSONException {
        String json = "[{"appId": "self","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "FN15","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"},{"appId": "bob","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "GN30","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"},{"appId": "Mnd","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "FN30","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"}]";
        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
            String Coupon = jsonobject.getString("issuingAgency");
            // logic to see if code is sorted or not 
        }
    }
```

Trying to see if *issuingAgency* is sorted in order of:

```
FN15 - FN30 - GN30
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "appId": "self",
    "askPrice": 0,
    "bidPrice": 0,
    "collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick",
    "collectionName": "data",
    "collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "collectionType": "LIVE",
    "coupon": 1.03,
    "createdBy": "Test",
    "createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "createdOnDate": 0,
    "forward": 0,
    "issuingAgency": "FN15",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "lastUpdatedBy": "string",
    "lastUpdatedDate": 0,
    "maturity": ,
    "midPrice":0 ,
    "mtaVersionNumber": 0,
    "settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"
  },
  {
    "appId": "bob",
    "askPrice": 0,
    "bidPrice": 0,
    "collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick",
    "collectionName": "data",
    "collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "collectionType": "LIVE",
    "coupon": 1.03,
    "createdBy": "Test",
    "createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "createdOnDate": 0,
    "forward": 0,
    "issuingAgency": "GN30",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "lastUpdatedBy": "string",
    "lastUpdatedDate": 0,
    "maturity": ,
    "midPrice":0 ,
    "mtaVersionNumber": 0,
    "settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"
  },
  {
    "appId": "Mnd",
    "askPrice": 0,
    "bidPrice": 0,
    "collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick",
    "collectionName": "data",
    "collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "collectionType": "LIVE",
    "coupon": 1.03,
    "createdBy": "Test",
    "createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "createdOnDate": 0,
    "forward": 0,
    "issuingAgency": "FN30",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z",
    "lastUpdatedBy": "string",
    "lastUpdatedDate": 0,
    "maturity": ,
    "midPrice":0 ,
    "mtaVersionNumber": 0,
    "settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"
  }
]
```

In the JSON given, the code would return false because issuingAgency is not sorted.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Keep track of the previous  ID, check whether current ID is lexicographically greater than the previous ID. If not return false.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is compare if current `issuingAgency` is smaller than it's previous one:

```
public void Trial () throws JSONException {
        String json = "[{"appId": "self","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "FN15","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"},{"appId": "bob","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "GN30","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"},{"appId": "Mnd","askPrice": 0,"bidPrice": 0,"collectionDataSource": "ExternalTick","collectionName": "data","collectionObservationTime": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","collectionType": "LIVE","coupon": 1.03,"createdBy": "Test","createdOn": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","createdOnDate": 0,"forward": 0,"issuingAgency": "FN30","lastUpdated": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z","lastUpdatedBy": "string","lastUpdatedDate": 0,"maturity": ,"midPrice":0 ,"mtaVersionNumber": 0,"settlementDate": "2020-09-21T17:47:59.703Z"}]";
        JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(json);
 
        boolean isOrdered = true;

        String lastCoupon = jsonObj.getJSONObject(0).getString("issuingAgency");
        for (int i = 1; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);
            String Coupon = jsonobject.getString("issuingAgency");
            // logic to see if code is sorted or not 
            if(Coupon.compareTo(lastCoupon) < 0){
               isOrdered = false;
               break;
            }
            lastCoupon = Coupon;
        }
        System.out.println("if ordered = " + isOrdered);
    }
```